# how to route spring cloud gateway to websocket service?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to route my websocket-service on spring cloud gateway

as spring cloud gateway docs, I tried to do this and it works :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: websocket-sockjs-route
        uri: http://localhost:8085
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/info/**
      - id: websocket_route
        uri: ws://localhost:8085
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/**
```

but when i tried this, it wont works :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: websocket-sockjs-route
        uri: http://websocket-service:8085
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/info/**
      - id: websocket_route
        uri: ws://websocket-service:8085
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/**
```

I want to make my websocket route become like this :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: hello-world-route
        uri: lb://hello-world:8081
        predicates:
        - Path=/hello
```

Answer (score 3):

you can have a look at this issue: [gateway](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/110)

and it should works by using this way:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: websocket-sockjs-route
        uri: http://websocket-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/info/**
      - id: websocket_route
        uri: lb:ws://websocket-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/**
```

and if you use discovery client, you need not to set the port, just use the service name.

Comment: and what about headers ? because when i call  websocket/info... i got httpcode 400, i think it can be because there are missing correct header attribute ... what do you think ?