# Spring Cloud gateway fails to establish websocket connections when server expects case sensitive headers

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I have a third party webapplication having websocket connections. It is expecting Upgrade, Connection header names to be case sensitive. I am using spring cloud gateway as a reverse proxy to this webapp. All the http calls are success but for websocket requests i am getting the following error

> io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshakeException:
> Invalid handshake response getStatus: 404 Not Found   at
> io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketClientHandshaker13.verify(WebSocketClientHandshaker13.java:272)
> ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65

WebSocketClientHandshaker is setting the upgrade and connection headers and it is in lower case. How do I override these header values ?

application.yml configuration is as below

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
              allowedOrigins: "*"
              allowedMethods: "*"
              allowedHeaders: "*"
      httpclient:
        pool:
          max-idle-time: 10s
      ssl:
        useInsecureTrustManager: true
      filter:
        remove-non-proxy-headers:
          headers:
            - Keep-Alive
            - TE
            - Trailer
            - Transfer-Encoding
      routes:
        - id : no_op
          uri: no://op
          predicates:
            - Path=/falcon/tunneling/**
        - id: reroute_ws
          uri: ws://localhost:5555
          predicates:
            - Path=/websocket/**
        - id: reroute_2
          uri: http://localhost:5555
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to route spring cloud gateway to websocket service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318478/how-to-route-spring-cloud-gateway-to-websocket-service)

Comment: @LucasCosta no. I am not using discovery and mine is not load balancer

Comment: I doubt it is because spring cloud send the headers in lower case. the webserver i am trying to access is having case sensitive check for headers

Comment: can you use a preserve headers to test it? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-preservehostheader-gatewayfilter-factory

Comment: not just the host header, i need to send Upgrade and Connecton headers case sensitive, currently it is all lower case and the third party server i am connecting doesnt support that.